# How can I fix the error E0277: the trait bound `[usize]: std::marker::Sized` is not satisfied?

Tags: rust

I'm trying to pass an array to a function:

```
fn my_func(xs: [usize]) -> usize {
    0
}

fn main() {
    let arr = [329, 457, 657];
    let res = my_func(inp);
}
```

I get the error:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `[usize]: std::marker::Sized` is not satisfied
 --> src/main.rs:1:12
  |
1 | fn my_func(xs: [usize]) -> usize {
  |            ^^ `[usize]` does not have a constant size known at compile-time
  |
  = help: the trait `std::marker::Sized` is not implemented for `[usize]`
  = note: all local variables must have a statically known size
```

I know about [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37670796/stdmarkersized-is-not-satisfied) [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51454572/implementing-read-trait-trait-bound-stderrorerror-static-stdmarker) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40023706/why-do-i-get-a-trait-bound-t-stdmarkersized-is-not-satisfied-when-i-tr) but they don't seem to apply to my simple situation.

How can I fix the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm trying to pass an array to a function
>
> ```
> fn my_func(xs: [usize])
> ```

This is **not an array**, it's a *slice*; that's the problem. Read [What is the difference between a slice and an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30794235/155423)

As the other answers mention, there are several potential avenues to solve the problem, depending on your goals:

- Slices (`[T]`) don't have a size
- Arrays (`[T; N]`) have a size
- References to slices (`&[T]`) have a size
- Boxed slices (`Box<[T]>`) have a size
- References to arrays (`&[T; N]`) have a size

and so on.

Answer (score 5):

Your problem (and the reason why a `&` fixes your problem) is, that a slice has no known size **at compile time**.

There are several solutions:

1. Use an explicit length

   ```
   fn foo(arr: [usize; 3]) { }
   ```

Using an explicit length will tell the compiler how large the array is and can now decide how much space to reserve for the array.

2. Use a reference

   ```
   fn foo(arr: &[usize]) { }
   ```

A reference points to the slice (a fat pointer in fact), which size is known at compile time (depends on your architecture, but typically 32/64 bit).

3. Use heap allocation

   ```
   fn foo(arr: Box<[usize]> { }
   ```

A box is a heap allocated element (in fact a pointer), so that size is known as well.

There are other container (`Rc`, `Arc`, ...) which accept a unsized element. You can spot them in the source code easily, because they have a requirement [`?Sized`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/marker/trait.Sized.html) for their template argument (see [`Box` example](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.60.0/src/alloc/boxed.rs.html#176)).